# Bootstrap Carousel Function Parameters

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm following a tutorial on animating a bootstrap carousel. But theres one bit I don't understand and that's how elems is related to each part I want to animate? Like how does the function know that elems relates to a certain element in html?

here's the tutorial incase you need more info https://www.sitepoint.com/bootstrap-carousel-with-css3-animations/

```
function doAnimations(elems) {
  var animEndEv = 'webkitAnimationEnd animationend';

  elems.each(function () {
    var $this = $(this),
        $animationType = $this.data('animation');

    // Add animate.css classes to
    // the elements to be animated 
    // Remove animate.css classes
    // once the animation event has ended
    $this.addClass($animationType).one(animEndEv, function () {
      $this.removeClass($animationType);
    });
  });
}

// Select the elements to be animated
// in the first slide on page load
var $firstAnimatingElems = $myCarousel.find('.item:first')
                           .find('[data-animation ^= "animated"]');

// Apply the animation using our function
doAnimations($firstAnimatingElems);

// Pause the carousel 
$myCarousel.carousel('pause');

// Attach our doAnimations() function to the
// carousel's slide.bs.carousel event 
$myCarousel.on('slide.bs.carousel', function (e) { 
  // Select the elements to be animated inside the active slide 
  var $animatingElems = $(e.relatedTarget)
                        .find("[data-animation ^= 'animated']");
  doAnimations($animatingElems);
});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is bootstrap's `slide.bs.carousel` event that does the trick. As per the bootstrap's [document](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#carousel-events) on carousel's event, this event has the property named `relatedTarget` which contains DOM elements being slid into place as the active item.

Your tutorial is further finding elements which have `data-animation` attribute and pass them in `doAnimations(elems)` function. Using `each` event, animation is being executed one by one on elements stored in the `elems`.

Tutorial's code is calling `doAnimations` manually for the first slide, however for all consecutive slides, bootstrap's event takes care of it.